# Special rewrite rule for .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Having issues trying to do a proper .htaccess rewrite with the following conditions

original URL:
http://example.com/foo/bar/ANYTHING   (either http or https, ANYTHING could be anything the user enters)

rewritten URL:
https://example.com/foo/bar/index.php/this/that/ANYTHING

but don't rewrite anything with index.php already in it.

I've tried several options, but I keep getting the filesystem path included in the new URL.

My attempt:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /foo/bar/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/foo/bar/index.php/this/that/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, test your rules *without* `301`, because the browser caches 301 results and makes testing much harder. Add `R=301` not until you're satisfied with the rules.
See also [Tips for debugging .htaccess rewrite rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542).

You don't need to test for `example.com`, unless multiple domains are hosted in the same directory.
Testing for `index.php` is against `REQUEST_URI`, not `HTTP_HOST`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteRule ^/?foo/bar/(.*)$ https://example.com/foo/bar/index.php/this/that/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks like it will take care of it!